# Center 3 text elements on one line in latex

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I am new to LaTeX and trying to write my first resume.  I want to list my contact info and right now I am doing this by using `\hfill`.  The problem is that `\hfill` equalizes the spacing but I want the bottom center (#3, 4 and 5) to not be spaced equally, but give up that equal spacing for that middle element to be centered horizontally.  Any tips on this?

```
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{geometry} % changes margins across the page
 \geometry{
 left=5mm,
 right=5mm,
 top=5mm,
 bottom=5mm,
}
\newcommand{\longcontact}[5]{
\center{  {\Gentsroom} #1 \hfill {\large} \hfill {\ComputerMouse} #2 }
\center{ {\Letter} #3 \hfill {\Telefon} #4  \hfill Github: #5}
}
```

[image: What I have right now]

Comment: Is `\center` a command? Does it work like `\center{..}`? `\begin{center} .. \end{center}` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @Manuel it will cause the rest of the document to be centred. Conversely `{\large}` does nothing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the centering to be effective, you have to ignore the widths:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marvosym}

\newcommand{\longcontact}[5]{% <--- don't forget
  \par % be sure to start a new line
  \Gentsroom\ #1 \hfill \ComputerMouse\ #2%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\Letter\ #3}% zero width
  \hfill % fill
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\Telefon\ #4}% zero width
  \hfill % fill
  \makebox[0pt][r]{Github: #5}%
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\longcontact{Something}{Hey!}{Whatever}{555 55 55}{Hub}

\end{document}
```

[image]